# How Should I Iterate a Sequence?

Tags: clojure

Below is my attempt to iterate a sequence of maps; the code fails due to the casting error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry`.

Can anyone explain/demonstrate how I *should* iterate the result-set? Thanks.

```
(with-connection db
                 (with-query-results rs ["select category from users group by category"]
                                     (doall
                                       (for [s [rs]] 
                                       (do (println (val s)))))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrapped the `rs` into a vector. So `s` will be bound to the whole sequence, not the individual map entries. So when you call `val` it doesn't know what to do with a sequence. Hence the exception. This should work:

```
(with-connection db
  (with-query-results rs ["select category from users group by category"]
    (doall
      (for [rec rs
            s   rec] 
        (do
          (println (val s)))))))
```

However the ugly `doall` and `do` around the `for` should ring a bell, that something could be improved. And indeed `for` is used to construct another lazy sequence. This does not work well with side-effects as you intend in your example. You should use `doseq`  in this case.

```
(with-connection db
  (with-query-results rs ["select category from users group by category"]
    (doseq [rec rs
            s   rec]
      (println (val s)))))
```

The interface for the bindings of `doseq` is identical to that of `for`. However it executes things immediatelly, and thusly realises any side-effects immediatelly. If you put multiple expressions in the body of a for, you have to wrap it into a `do`. This is a reminder that the body should produce a value. Multiple expressions however indicate side-effects. `doseq` therefore wraps the body into a `do` for you. So you can easily have multiple expressions. For illustration:

```
(doall
  (for [s seq-of-maps]
    (do
      (println (key s))
      (println (val s)))))

(doseq [s seq-of-maps]
  (println (key s))
  (println (val s)))))
```

As a rule of thumb: you need side-effects? Look for things starting in `do`!

As a rule of thumb 2: if something looks ugly (see above comparison), this should ring a bell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example. The biggest stumbling block I encountered was dealing with the result set, i.e. "rs". In my mind it was counter intuitive to essentially create a sequence from a sequence -- `[s rs]` -- since as I understand it "rs" is already a sequence. My mind was stuck on iterating the "rs" sequence directly.

Comment: Also, it seems in order to use `key` or `val` we first need to do: `[rec result-set recsq rec]` Essentially, we need to do: result-set -> record (hashmap) -> sequence. There's a much better explanation [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698959/error-thrown-while-processing-db-query-resultset)

Comment: @dj3 I hadn't looked in detail what your sequence actually looks like. I just saw that the `[rs]`. I edited the answer to give a correct result.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it sounds like you are trying to do a DB query from Clojure. You may have to supply more information about the "users" table for instance and what your query result set looks like.

At any rate, something like this *may* work

```
(def a  (with-query-results rs ["select category from users group by category"]
          (doall rs)))

(map #(:category %) a)
```