# Error Thrown While Processing DB Query Resultset

Tags: clojure

Can anyone help me understand why my code (see below) is resulting in the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   nth not supported on this type: PersistentStructMap

```
(defn search [query]
  (with-connection db 
    (with-query-results rs [query] 
      (doseq [[k v] rs] 
        (println v)))))

(search (nth *command-line-args* 0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rs` is a sequence (list), representing all the records in your resultset.  Each element of `rs` is a hashmap representing a single record, with key/value pairs in the map representing field names and values for that record.  You're trying to do the equivalent of this:

```
user> (let [rs [{:id 1 :val "foo"} {:id 2 :val "bar"}]]
        (doseq [[k v] rs]
          (println v)))
; Evaluation aborted.
; nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
```

This is trying to destructure each map into `[k v]`, doing the rough equivalent of this:

```
user> (let [k (nth {:id 1 :val "foo"} 0)
            v (nth {:id 1 :val "foo"} 1)])
; Evaluation aborted.
; nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
```

If you're trying to print the value for every field in every record, you need to do this:

```
user> (let [rs [{:id 1 :val "foo"} {:id 2 :val "bar"}]]
        (doseq [record rs
                [k v] record]
          (println v)))
foo
1
bar
2
```

"For each record in the resultset, for each key/value in that record, print the value."

If your resultset contains only a single record (or you only care about one of them) and you're trying to iterate over the fields of that single record, then pass `doseq` only the `first`:

```
user> (let [rs [{:id 1 :val "foo"}]]
        (doseq [[k v] (first rs)]
          (println v)))
foo
1
```

"For every key/value in the first record of the resultset, print the value."

Comment: Thanks for the well-thought out and clear explanation; it was very helpful. I mistakenly believed that `rs` was "a list of two-item vectors, one for each key/value pair in the map" [(See "How to Iterate Over Map Keys and Values)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685916/how-to-iterate-over-map-keys-and-values) rather than a sequence of hashmaps.